# Ejecutar exe Node js con parametros

Tags: javascript, nodejs, parametros, exe, ejecutar

Estoy estancado en algo que simple que no puedo resolverlo, estoy haciendo en pequeño proyecto de lanzador de juegos con node y electron, por lo que requiero lanzar programas como steam, epic games, chrome con parametros

```
function RunExeFile(pathExe, arg){
    var child = require('child_process').execFile;
  var executablePath = pathExe;
  var parameters = arg;
  
  child(executablePath, parameters, function(err, data) {
       console.log(err)
       console.log(data.toString());
  });
  
      }
```

el caso es que si envio arg, no se ejecuta, tampoco tira error, si no envio arg ejecuta sin problemas

```
function createDomIconsleft(iconleft){
 
    const IconsleftHtml=`<li class="nav-item nav-settings d-none d-lg-block">
    <a class="nav-link" href="" onclick="RunExeFile(${iconleft.link} ${iconleft.parameters}">
      <i class=""><img src="assets/images/file-icons/plataforms/${iconleft.image}" class="img-thumbnail rounded-circle" alt="${iconleft.title}"></i>
    </a>
  </li>`
  return IconsleftHtml;
}
```

${iconleft.link} ${iconleft.parameters} los traigo de un json

```
"link": "C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\Application\\\\chrome.exe",

    "parameters": "--incognito",

    "title": "Chrome",

    "image": "google.png"
```

Comment: Y la pregunta razonable que me hago es ... ¿ Que le estás pasando como `parameters` ? Aprovecho para recomendarte la lectura de lo que es un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: La documentación dice: `args <string[]>: List of string arguments`. Es decir, un *array* de cadenas. Por lo tanto, si le estás pasando `parameters` tal y como lo obtienes del array, simplemente cambia por `child(executablePath, [ parameters ], function(err, data)`.

Comment: ya lo resolví, muchas gracias!!!